# excel processing in c#

Tags: c#, excel, .net-3.5

I am developing a job application. Each job generates an excel file. I will have 50 parallel job. So 50 excel files will be generated parallelly.

I am using C#3.5 and Excel 2003. The problem is I am unable to instantiate more Excel objects. I am getting COMException. So do I need to create excel processing only one at a time? Do you have any solution for this?

Pls help me.

Edit:

The excel genration doesn't need user interaction. Its a scheduled job.

I am generating Excel (xls). I need to do formatting and coloring in excel, so I can't use csv. Now I have synchronized the code, so at a time only one job processes Excel. But its taking too much time, since only one excel processing at a time.

Any kind of Excel pooling logic will help? Please direct me.

Comment: Do you have 50 open files in the same time? could you provide some code?

Comment: What exact format are you generating? .xls? .xslx? .csv?

Comment: Do you really need 50 files?  Can you use one file with 50 worksheets in it?

Comment: Yes. I need 50 files. Each file will be emailed to different user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you would need to start 50 instances of Excel, that would not work.

You have 3 options:

- Use [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&displaylang=en). This allows you to write to an excel file as if it was an xml file. No need to start Excel.
- Use SharePoint Excel Services. This allows you to do server side Excel processing. No need to start Excel. The problem with this is that the SharePoint version that includes Excel Services is expensive.
- Process the files one at a time, as you suggested.

Comment: Open XML is supported in Excel 2007. But I need to support Excel 2003.

Comment: Since Open XML is the only option for my problem. Moving to Excel 2007 and open xml.

Answer (score 1):

ooooh i once have that kind of problem b4.

my solution is i use html excel. honestly, its kinda stupid solution, but it work pretty well and very easy to implement.

1 create html template a bit like this

```
<html>
<body>
name - <div>$<name>$</div>
</body>
</html>
```

2 read your template as string

```
System.IO.StreamReader stream = new System.IO.StreamReader("");
string template = stream.ReadToEnd();
template = template.Replace("$<name>$", "John");
```

3 then save your string as .xls

**to create a template sheets is very easy.

1 create excel template like u normally do in excel

2 in the cell u want to replace yout value type in $$name$$ *note that above i use $<'value'>$. but if we do this way i suggest u cahnge to $$name$$ becus for < and > excel gonna do HtmlEncode for us

3 u can create many sheets as u like

4 'Save as' .mht

5 then later change file.mht to .xls and string.Replace("$$name$$", "John");

Comment: In my past life I have done this and it works pretty well. Excel is basically tabular data. You use quite a lot of formatting using HTML tags and excel will properly open your file.

Comment: pls redirect me to some links, so I can get more information on this. My scenario is I will have a excel sheet which contains multiple sheets, I need to format excel, create charts in it. Using this html type can I generate charts?

Answer (score 0):

Does the generation of 50 excel files require user interaction?
If not, you can create a nightly job that generates files.

If it is a plain text kind of a format(or CSV), you don't need Excel.
Also, you can use one excel instance to generate all the files, one after the other.